# Android, how to get the list of the apps that open a URL without using createChooser

Tags: android

To find all the apps that open a URL I would do like this:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose navigator");
    activity.startActivity(intentChooser);
```

The problem is that I don't want to user the Chooser control, because of some developing specifications.

The question is how can I get the list of apps that open URL (that's what I get with the code above) to pass them to an ArrayAdapter / Spinner.

Comment: IF you find the solution please kindly post it back, I am looking into this too. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try asking PackageManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
List<ResolveInfo> allActivities = queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Comment: I think you meant to say `context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);` :)